# Function with multiple functions?

Tags: calculus

g(2x) - g(x) when g(t) = 8/t - 6t.

How is this solved? I have:

8/2x - 8/x - 6(2x) - 6x.

Is that right?

Comment: It's not even clear what you mean. Do you mean $g(t) = \frac{8}{t} - 6t$ or $g(t) = \frac{8}{t-6t}$ or...?

Comment: Assuming you mean $g(t) = \frac{8}{t} - 6t$ then $$g(2x) - g(x) = \frac{8}{2x} - 12x - \frac{8}{x} + 6x = -\frac{4}{x}-6x$$

Comment: Is this how to do it?

http://i.imgur.com/qzRvPla.jpg

Answer (score 1):

By replacing you have:

$$
g(2t)-g(t)=4/t-12t-8/t+6t=-4/t-6t
$$

Comment: But what happens to 2t?

Comment: it is put inside the $g(.)$.......

Comment: Is this how to do it?

http://i.imgur.com/qzRvPla.jpg

Comment: No there is nothing more to do, it is done. Unless you want it equal to zero?